# getting image to overlap image inside div inside wrapper

Tags: css, image, html

i got a wrapper Im trying to fit image in and have a logo go over top of it lower middle Im having trouble coding it... i can get image on top or bottom or into the menu part below the wrapper but i cant seem to work it out

Comment: No information = no help. You've got to give us something to work with (HTML, CSS, etc) preferably a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You do it using positioning.

**Working example** http://jsfiddle.net/UKxK6/

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <img class="bg" src="img path" />
 <img class="logo" src="logo path" />
</div>
```

CSS:

## wrapper {

position: relative;
}

```
#wrapper .bg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 5;
}

#wrapper .logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/pt4rV/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the float and clear attribute in your CSS may be it will help you. and also use MAX-WIDTH and MAX-height property so you are able to get  proper output.

[image][image]

with max-height and max-width property you are able to set maximum height and width and use float:left or right and clear property as per your need to set the image.